# Why does HTTP Basic Auth works using `git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic <base64>"`, but not when putting credentials directly in the URL?

Tags: git, http, version-control, basic-authentication

I've the following "dummy" credentials (username and PAT) for accessing a repository:

```
bd6164:o6g5xae5fmqeqdbjatdfjichdk55lweq4jxyt2jvwtjuzxdwwgxa
```

Now, according to MS documentation, I should supply these credentials to `git` using `git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic <base64>" ...`, which results in successful authentication.

However, if I supply these credentials to `git` directly in the URL:

`https://bd6164:o6g5xae5fmqeqdbjatdfjichdk55lweq4jxyt2jvwtjuzxdwwgxa@azuredevops.example.net`

then authentication fails.

Normally, when I use `git`, I can put my credentials directly in the URL for successful authentication, so why do I experience these inconsistencies? In general, aren't credentials in the URL converted to Base64 and sent in a "Authorization: Basic" HTTP header?

Here is the documentation from MS on how to use PAT with `git`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat

**Works**:

```
# git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic YmQ2MTY0Om82ZzV4YWU1Zm1xZXFkYmphdGRmamljaGRrNTVsd2VxNGp4eXQyanZ3dGp1enhkd3dneGE=" clone https://azuredevops.example.net/Main/MyProj/_git/MyRepo
```

**Fails**:

```
# git clone https://bd6164:o6g5xae5fmqeqdbjatdfjichdk55lweq4jxyt2jvwtjuzxdwwgxa@azuredevops.example.net/Main/MyProj/_git/MyRepo
```

Comment: Does it work with curl ? or opening the url in your browser (without any valid auth cookie, from a private window for example) ?

Comment: It's weird, using Curl it works with PAT.

Comment: @LeGEC - I debugged it using HTTP proxy, and the reason why Curl succeds and Git fails, is that Git attempts to use NTLM authentication, since Azure DevOps responds with an `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` to initial request. However, Curl just use HTTP Basic Auth. Is there a way to force Git to use HTTP Basic Auth?

Comment: This looks like a question for Google :) [This github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/353) indicates several things, like manually setting credentials in the local credential manager, or running `git config credential.authority basic`

Answer (score 4):

Before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), sensitive data in the HTTP trace were supposed to be redacted, but we failed to do so in HTTP/2 requests.

See [commit b66c77a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b66c77a64e696eb5e5994a58c0d50073f8e93bf1) (22 Sep 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 58e2bc4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58e2bc452b0539977eff6431d63867030429e2f4), 03 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b66c77a64e696eb5e5994a58c0d50073f8e93bf1): match headers case-insensitively when redacting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When HTTP/2 is in use, we fail to correctly redact "Authorization" (and other) headers in our `GIT_TRACE_CURL` output.
>
> We get the headers in our `CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION` callback, `curl_trace()`.
> It passes them along to `curl_dump_header()`, which in turn checks `redact_sensitive_header()`.
> We see the headers as a text buffer like:
>
> ```
> Host: ...
> Authorization: Basic ...
> ```
>
> After breaking it into lines, we match each header using `skip_prefix()`.
> This is case-sensitive, even though HTTP headers are case-insensitive.
> This has worked reliably in the past because these headers are generated by curl itself, which is predictable in what it sends.
>
> But when HTTP/2 is in use, instead we get a lower-case "authorization:" header, and we fail to match it.
> The fix is simple: we should match with `skip_iprefix()`.
>
> There's one other way to demonstrate the issue (and how I actually found it originally).
> Looking at `GIT_TRACE_CURL` output against `github.com`, you'll see the unredacted output, even if you didn't set `http.version`.
> That's because setting it is only necessary for curl to send the extra headers in its HTTP/1.1 request that say "Hey, I speak HTTP/2; upgrade if you do, too".
> But for a production site speaking https, the server advertises via ALPN, a TLS extension, that it supports HTTP/2, and the client can immediately start using it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the interaction of `git`, git credential manager, and a server announcing it supports NTLM.

Found in [this issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/353) :

- OP says he fixed the issue by manually setting login/password for the target domain in his credentials manager,
- maintainer suggests to also try setting `git config credential.authority basic` in git config